# Redirect Posts to Categories in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I've been scouring the Internet looking for an answer to this but haven't yet. On a WordPress site, how do I redirect all posts from a particular category to that category page rather than the single post view using the .htaccess file? For example, I have the following category location:

```
www.example.com/websites/
```

which will show all posts in the "websites" category. I have a post in this category at the following location:

```
www.example.com/websites/some-website-example/
```

When the search results on my site show a link to my Some Website Example post and the user clicks on it, how do I get them to go to the category page instead of the single post view? In other words I want them to always go to,`www.example.com/websites/` instead of `www.example.com/websites/some-website-example/`, or `www.example.com/websites/another-example/`, or any other single post.

I am very new to modifying the .htaccess file, so what code do I need and where do I put it? Here's what I have:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

And again, what I want is a rule that redirects all requests for pages under the /websites/ directory to the /websites/ directory itself.

p.s. For those of you who need a reason for why I would do this, I'm using the site as a portfolio and would like users to see all my website with their descriptions and other post information together on the page all at once, and never want them to see a single website on the page.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to set a 301 redirection on .htaccess.

```
redirect 301 /old/old.htm http://www.you.com/new.htm
```

However, I don't think it is a good idea. If I would need to do such a thing, I'd add to my WP instance non public post-type for example "websites items". Then you should add a **page** named "websites". If you have a page, you can make a custom query on page-websites.php template file.

That should work and your standard Wordpress RSS shoudn't have te "webistes/website1" sites, so Google won't go there anyway.

[Here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) is the CODEX site with all possible information about registering post-types. It's really nice feature provided since WP 3.0.